# Find max and extract data from a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a text file with twenty car prices and its serial number there are 50 lines in this file. I would like to find the max car price and its serial for every 10 lines.

priceandserial.txt

```
102030 4000.30
102040 5000.40
102080 5500.40
102130 4000.30
102140 5000.50
102180 6000.50
102230 2000.60
102240 4000.30
102280 6000.30
102330 9000.70
102340 1000.30
102380 3000.30
102430 4000.80
102440 5000.30
102480 7000.30
```

When I tried Python's builtin max function I get 102480 as the max value.

```
x = np.loadtxt('carserial.txt', unpack=True)

print('Max:', np.max(x))
```

Desired result:

```
102330 9000.70
102480 7000.30
```

There are 50 lines in file, therefore I should have a 5 line result with serial and max prices of each 10 lines.

Comment: Note that you're not using "Python's builtin max function", but Numpy's `max` function. It shouldn't surprise that you're getting `102480` as the max, since you're not telling numpy what column you're interested in, so it just looks at the first column. And you're not telling it to look at the data in 10 line chunks, so it looks at all of them - the max value for the first column for all lines is 102480. Perhaps try solving the problem and asking about problems with that solution?

Comment: Yes I'm sorry about that. I a beginner and my only resource is online materials. I recently heard about stackoverflow where i can ask questions. The reason i'm using numpy is because of the youtube video i followed the person was always using import numpy as np. I don't know what it does but i'm getting there.

Answer (score 1):

Respectfully, I think the first solution is over-engineered. You don't need `numpy` or `math` for this task, just a dictionary. As you loop through, you update the dictionary if the latest value is greater than the current value, and do nothing if it isn't. Everything 10th item, you append the values from the dictionary to an output list and reset the buffer.

```
with open('filename.txt', 'r') as opened_file:
    data = opened_file.read()

rowsplitdata = data.split('\n')
colsplitdata = [u.split(' ') for u in rowsplitdata]
x = [[int(j[0]), float(j[1])] for j in colsplitdata]

output = []
buffer = {"max":0, "index":0}
count = 0
#this assumes x is a list of lists, not a numpy array
for u in x:
    count += 1
    if u[1] > buffer["max"]:
        buffer["max"] = u[1]
        buffer["index"] = u[0]
    if count == 10:
        output.append([buffer["index"], buffer["max"]])
        buffer = {"max":0, "index":0}
        count = 0
#append the remainder of the buffer in case you didn't get to ten in the final pass
output.append([buffer["index"], buffer["max"]])
output
[[102330, 9000.7], [102480, 7000.3]]
```

Comment: Getting this error: if u[1] > buffer["max"]:
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'

Comment: You need to parse the solumns into floats, which I assumed you had already done. Updating code to reflect this.

Comment: Still getting error: line 36, in <module>
    x = [[int(j[0]), float(j[1])] for j in colsplitdata]
  File "C:\lara\loop.py", line 36, in <listcomp>
    x = [[int(j[0]), float(j[1])] for j in colsplitdata]
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

Comment: try `[[j[0], float(j[1])] for j in colsplitdata]`. If that is throwing an error, your source data file is not as described.

Comment: you can also try substituting `\r` for `\n` when splitting

Comment: I keep getting an error. I guess i have to put this to rest.
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '4479.43\n100994'

Comment: There is a  `\n` character is in the middle of your string. If you split on `\n` as my code does, this wouldn't be possible. Look up the behavior of `split()`

Answer (score 0):

You should iterate over it and for each 10 lines extract the maximum:

```
import math

# New empty list for colecting the results
max_list=[]

#iterate thorught x supposing
for i in range(math.ceil(len(x)/10)):
   ### append only 10 elments if i+10 is not superior to the lenght of the array
   if i+11<len(x):    
       max_list=max_list.append(np.max(x[i:i+11]))
   ### if it is superior, then append all the remaining elements
   else:
       max_list=max_list.append(np.max(x[i:]))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can transpose your input first, then use `np.split` and for each submatrix you calculate its max.

```
x = np.genfromtxt('carserial.txt', unpack=True).T
print(x)
for submatrix in np.split(x,len(x)//10):
    print(max(submatrix,key=lambda l:l[1]))
```

[working example](https://repl.it/@giulianooliveira/iara)

Answer (score 0):

This should do your job.

```
number_list = [[],[]]
with open('filename.txt', 'r') as opened_file:
    for line in opened_file:
        if len(line.split()) == 0:
            continue
        else:
            a , b = line.split(" ")
            number_list[0].append(a)
            number_list[1].append(b)
col1_max, col2_max = max(number_list[0]), max(number_list[1])
col1_max, col2_max
```

Just change the `filename`. `col1_max`, `col2_max` have the respective column's max value. You can edit the code to accommodate more columns.